# Relationship and interpretation of "discrete" and "continuous" covariance matrices in Kalman Filtering

Tags: control-engineering, statistics, kalman-filters

I am quite confused about the interpretations/implementation of the system and measurement noise covariance matrices for the continuous and discrete time Kalman Filter. What I want is to initialize those matrices with physically meaningful values for the *continuous* system (think continuously, implement discrete).

I know that the standard deviation has the same unit as the corresponding quantitiy, e.g., for the (arbitrary) system
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=Ax+Bu+w,\quad &w\in\mathcal{N}(0,Q_c)\\
y&=Cx+v,\quad &v\in\mathcal{N}(0,R_c)
\end{align}
$$
if $x=[s,\,v]^\top$ are the position and velocity of a falling particle, respectively, the covariances $Q_c=\text{diag}(\sigma_{w,\,1}^2,\,\sigma_{w,\,2}^2)$ have the units [m$^2$/s$^2$] and [m$^2$/s$^4$] (since the standard deviations have the same units as $\dot s$ and $\dot v$), and $R_c=\sigma_v^2$ has unit [m$^2$] (the same as $s$).  So far so good.
For the sake of completeness, the **discrete-time Kalman Filter** ​equations read
$$
\begin{align}
&\textbf{Time update}\\
&\hat{x}^-_k=A_d\hat{x}^+_{k-1}+B_du_{k-1}\\
&P^-_k=A_dP_{k-1}^+A_d^\top+Q_{k-1}\\
&\textbf{Measurement Update}\\
&K_k=P_k^-C^\top\left(CP_k^-C^\top+R_k\right)^{-1}\\
&\hat{x}^+_k=\hat{x}^-_k+K_k(y_k-Cx^-_k)\\
&P_k^+=(I-K_kC)P^-_k
\end{align}
$$
where $A_d=(I+\Delta tA),\quad B_d=\Delta tB$ using a forward Euler.
Now, according to "Optimal State Estimation: Kalman, H-Infinity, and Nonlinear Approaches" by D. Simon p.231 ff
it is mentioned that
$$Q_c=\frac{Q_{k-1}}{\Delta t},\qquad R_c={R_{k}}\Delta t$$
and one can substitute these expressions in the discrete KF equations (and look at the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$) to derive the **continuous-time Kalman-Bucy Filter**
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\hat{x}}&=A\hat{x}+Bu+K(y-C\hat{x})\\
\dot{P}&=-PC^\top R_c^{-1}CP+AP+PA^\top+Q_c
\end{align}
$$
where $K=PC^\top R_c^{-1}$.

**QUESTION**

It is not clear to me **why the covariances scale with the discretization time**? For example if I were to look at the sensor measuring the position and it would tell me in its data sheet it has standard deviation, say, $\sigma_v=0.2\,m$, and I were to implement the discrete KF with a sampling time of $\Delta t=0.01\,s$, i.e. $100\,Hz$, then
$$R_k=\frac{\sigma_v^2}{\Delta t}=\frac{0.04\,m^2}{0.01\,s}=4\frac{m^2}{s}$$
so the "uncertainty" in my measurements would blow up, even though I receive more measurements (which should be a good thing?)! On the other hand, let's say we're not confident with the model so we expect the velocity and acceleration varies with standard deviation $\sigma_{w,\,1}=0.1\,\frac{m}{s}$ and $\sigma_{w,\,2}=1\,\frac{m}{s^2}$. For the discrete KF,
$$
\begin{align}
Q_{k-1}&=\Delta t\ \text{diag}(\sigma_{w,\,1}^2,\,\sigma_{w,\,2}^2)\\
&=0.01\,s
\begin{bmatrix}
 0.1\,\frac{m^2}{s^2}& 0\\
0& 1\,\frac{m^2}{s^4}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0.001\,\frac{m^2}{s}& 0\\
0& 0.01\,\frac{m^2}{s^3}
\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$
meaning that our model gets "better" with smaller step size. This makes somewhat sense, since the discretization gets more accurate, right? Is my reasoning correct? Or did I miss something. Is there a way to interpret the discrete covariances? I never actually see coded Kalman Filters take this into account. Why is that?

EDIT1: Additional question, if I want to add noise to my measurements in Matlab, do I use $R_c$ or $R_{k}$, i.e.,

`yk = C*xk+sqrt(Rc)*randn(1,1)`

or

`yk = C*xk+sqrt(Rk)*randn(1,1)`

EDIT2: Changes example system to make more sense